# Doctrine dql select as with spaces

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, doctrine-query

I would like to know if it's possible to alias a column name with spaces in for example

```
$query = "SELECT u.firstName AS 'First Name' FROM User u";
$result = $query->getResult( Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY );
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible using doctrine DQL, your chance perhaps is to get a PDO instance and write a native SQL query which must support what you want.

Comment: I have managed to get this working using native query and using the result mapping class, but obviously doesn't use my soft delete filter for example, so hence why having to use dql

Comment: Have you tried using back ticks \`First Name\`?  Doubt if it will work but maybe.

Comment: Yes I've tried that already